# Unable to refresh page when using Angular, jQM, and Adapter

Tags: angularjs, routes, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a web page that is using Angular, jQuery Mobile, and the jQuery Mobile Angular adapter by tigbro.  I have everything up an running and it works great except for one issue and that is if at any point if you refresh the page using the browser's refresh button it will give a 404 error as if it doesn't understand the route anymore. I'm not sure where the issue might be since it gets a little confusing with the two frameworks and the adapter working together and I'm new to all of these technologies.

IE happens to be the only browser this doesn't happen in and the difference seems to be in the url.  Here is what it looks like when you browse to a page in IE:
http://site.com/SalesManagement/SalesManagementIndex.aspx#!/ViewNotes/4

Here is what it looks like when you browse to the same page in another browser like Chrome:
http://site.com/SalesManagement/ViewNotes/4

If you go to the first url in Chrome it will load the page and then rewrite the url to the 2nd one.

Below is my routing configuration:

```
var SalesManagementApp = angular.module('SalesManagementApp', [])

SalesManagementApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/Search', { templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerSearchView.aspx' })
    .when('/SearchResults', { templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerResultsView.aspx' })
    .when('/ViewNotes/:growerIndexKey', { templateUrl: 'Views/NotesHistoryView.aspx' })
    .when('/EditNote/:growerIndexKey/:noteIndexKey', { templateUrl: 'Views/UpsertNoteView.aspx' })
    .when('/AddNote/:growerIndexKey', { templateUrl: 'Views/UpsertNoteView.aspx' })
    .when('/', { templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerSearchView.aspx' })
    .otherwise({ templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerSearchView.aspx' }); 
} ]);
```

I've read some about html5 mode verse hashbang mode but setting html5 mode to off or on in the configuration just made my routing not work at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out thanks to a similar question on the github site for the adapter: https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter/issues/163

The fix for this is to disable html5Mode in angular and prefix your links with the # character. This makes your urls a little uglier as you are no longer using the html5 history API but in my case that doesn't matter.  Optionally you can specify a hash prefix (by default it seems to be !) but I set mine to empty string. I couldn't find any documentation telling me why this is useful but its important to know what the prefix is so you can properly set your links.

Below is my updated routing configuration.  Notice I now inject the $locationProvider.

```
var SalesManagementApp = angular.module('SalesManagementApp', [])

SalesManagementApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix("");

$routeProvider
    .when('/Search', { templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerSearchView.aspx' })
    .when('/SearchResults', { templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerResultsView.aspx' })
    .when('/ViewNotes/:growerIndexKey', { templateUrl: 'Views/NotesHistoryView.aspx' })
    .when('/EditNote/:growerIndexKey/:noteIndexKey', { templateUrl: 'Views/UpsertNoteView.aspx' })
    .when('/AddNote/:growerIndexKey', { templateUrl: 'Views/UpsertNoteView.aspx' })
    .when('/', { templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerSearchView.aspx' })
    .otherwise({ templateUrl: 'Views/GrowerSearchView.aspx' }); // jQuery Mobile seems to ignore the / and just use .otherwise.

$compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);

if (!localStorage.SessionInfo)
    window.location = '/Login.aspx';

} ]);
```

My links now look like: #/ViewNotes/{{growerIndexKey}}